# Password with special character ($) on Linux (mount statement)

Tags: r, linux, ubuntu

I want to perform a mount statement on Linux. My password contains the special character "$". My password is : ABC$$2010$$2009$

I tried :

```
#1 - Specify where in LINUX Environment the WINDOWS PATH will be MOUNTED
WinShare<-as.character("/opt/samples/Apps/LoadWindowsPath/WinShare/")

#2 - LINUX Command Line: Linux commands to MOUNT throught Server Message Block (SMB) with Common Internet File System (CIFS) option
Mount_MODEL_Path<-as.character(paste("echo 'PPP' | sudo -u root mount -t cifs //XXX.XXX.XXX.XX/SubDirectory/My.Folder -o username=\"Domain\\user name\",password=ABC$$2010$$2009$ ",WinShare,sep=""))

system(Mount_MODEL_Path)
```

It isn't working, they tell me that "Access is denied" whereas when I test locally I have the permission to access to "SubDirectory/My.Folder".

Comment: Escape the $ signs by putting a backslash in front of them: `password=ABC\$\$2010\$\$2009\$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape it with a Backslash like this '\$' this tells the Shell to ignore the Special Character.
Also i hope this is not your Real Password.

Comment: Thanks for the answer !  I put in my code :

Mount_MODEL_Path<-as.character(paste("echo 'PPP' | sudo -u root mount -t cifs //XXX.XXX.XXX.XX/SubDirectory/My.Folder -o username=\"Domain\\user name\",password=ABC\$\$2010\$\$2009\$ ",WinShare,sep=""))
system(Mount_MODEL_Path)

But they tell me that '$' isn't recognised in a character chain beginning with ""echo ...

Comment: Try surrounding your password wit Apostrophs like this 'ABC$$2010$$2009$'

Comment: Or maybe youre missing a third " on sep="" to close the paste("

Comment: did you try out  the third quotation mark  on sep="" to close the paste(" ?

Comment: If I put Apostrophs I obtain "mount error 13 = Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g.man mount.cifs)"... And if I try with  '\$' directly without the paste statement I obtain "mount error 13 = Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g.man mount.cifs)" too. I also tried to replace $ with %24 but it isn't working.

Comment: Not yet. I'll try